# From an extjs combobox for Rally builds, how do I fetch a field on the child ChangeSets records?

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

Using SDK 2, I created a combobox that lets me select a build.  I have a listener that wants to do something with the array of ChangeSets, but the array is only returning the attribute information (ref, etc). In the olden days, I could fetch the fields I wanted on a parent and see them in the children, too.  So, how do I get the ChangeSets to provide a Revision, say?

Here is the definition of the combobox:

```
this.down('#buildSelector').add({
        xtype: 'rallycombobox',
        displayField: 'Number',
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            select: function(combo, records, eOpts){
                this._buildResults(combo.getRecord().data);//Build
            },
            ready: function(combo, records, eOpts){
                this._buildResults(combo.getRecord().data);//Build
            }
        },
        width: 280,   
        storeConfig: {
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'Build',
            pagesize: 20, //# of builds displayed in drop down
             sorters: [{
                        property: 'CreationDate',
                        direction: 'DESC'
                      }],

            listeners: {
                load: function(store, records, successful){
                        console.log("dropdown records", records);
                    }
                }
            }
    });
```

That console log gives me something like this

```
dropdown records 
  Array[200]
    [0 … 13]
      0: Ext.Class.newClass
        data: Object
        BuildDefinition: Object
        Changesets: Array[2]
          0: Object
            _rallyAPIMajor: "1"
            _rallyAPIMinor: "31"
            _ref: "https://audemo.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/changeset/1260800.js"
            _refObjectName: "BuildHealthReportRepo:1000"
            _type: "Changeset"
            __proto__: Object
          1: Object
```

etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding a fetch property with an array of field names to your storeConfig object. If you just wanted to get the Build Number, Changesets and Revisions, the property definition could look like this:

```
storeConfig: {
        fetch: ['Number', 'Changesets', 'Revision'],
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'Build',
        pagesize: 20, //# of builds displayed in drop down
        sorters: [{
                    property: 'CreationDate',
                    direction: 'DESC'
                  }],

        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records, successful){
                console.log("dropdown records", records);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The key was putting it into the config (and remembering Changesets).